# Windows 11 Explorer lags for a second when selecting an image

Tags: performance, windows-explorer, windows-11, lag

Recently upgraded to Windows 11, noticed that in explorer if I click on an image, it takes about a second, showing the loading circle on my cursor before it fully selects. I noticed during this time this section ([Image of problem area in Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BmzV.png)) where it says "Set as background", "Rotate..." seems to be appearing. It takes about a second to appear. If I de-select the image and select a non-image, it also lags for about a second, while that section with "Set as background" takes a second to go away. Toggling between non-images works fine.

Basically, it appears that this bar that dynamically pops in with "set as background" is the source of the slowdown. Can this be disabled somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly the slow down is because of One Drive syncing

Comment: Try: (1) Reduce the number of columns in Explorer, (2) Switch Explorer to full-screen mode (press F11) and then exiting this mode (F11 again).

Comment: Happens irrespective of full-screen and columns visible, unfortunately

Comment: I did quite a bit of work with One Drive (on and off both) and (1) if the delay is short ignore it and (2) if the delay bothers you, fix One Drive.  This is how Windows 11 works.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much confirmed (work on my side) that One Drive syncing is responsible for the small slowdown. I see it here.

Two solutions:

(1) You use One Drive:   Just live with the slowdown.

(2) You do not use One Drive:  Unlink the PC to stop One Drive syncing.

If (in your case) you are very sure you removed One Drive (power shell needed to remove), then the small delay is most likely Windows looking for One Drive and finding it does not exist.  Not much you can do about that.

Comment: I don't appear to have OneDrive installed. In Add or Remove programs it is not there.

Comment: Open Settings Search then  One Drive  .   I am sure it is there in Windows 11

Comment: Not in settings either. I'm pretty confident I removed it a few years ago when I was on Win10.